# How to use OnClick in android programming

Tags: android, onclick

I am completely new to programming and I am trying to create an android app. At the moment I am trying to understand how to use OnClick() to make it so my button on MainActivity links to another activity.

Comment: have you googled it ? This post seems you have not googled about this thing 1st

Comment: I did google it, but all the answers seem confusing, again I am pretty much new to programming. I read up on it on android developers but it seems you need at least some programming knowledge for the site.

Comment: @user1928981 : post your Activity code from which you want to go second activity

Comment: if you are new bee than start with a handy book on android for beginners and study things to get clear thing other wise u`l be mingled in certain thing 
your answer can be given here but 1st  use your search power

Comment: I suggest you read the entire section here: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html Also, you can learn Java here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For doing some Action on Button Click following these Steps :

**STEP 1:**

Add a button in your Activity layout as:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_id_here"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

---

**STEP 2:**

Add your `NextActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` as:

```
 <!-- your other xml  -->
 <application
  <!-- your other xml  -->
        <activity
            android:name=".NextActivity" />

 </application>
```

---

**STEP 3:**

In MainActivity code add a Button click Listener to button_id_here as:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button_test;  //<< Create Button instance here
    Intent intent;       //<< For starting new Activity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Add layout to Activity here
        setContentView(R.layout.your_Activity_layout);

         // Initilie button here
         button_test= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id_here);

               // add a onclick listner to button here
         button_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
              intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);

              startActivity(intent); //<<< start Activity here
            }
        });
     }

}
```

---

if still facing to do some activity on Button click then learn  here:

https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
        String info = "Extra info";
        btn= findViewById(R.id.btn);


        btn.setOnClickListener (new onClickListener(){
             Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
             //If you need to pass any information
             i.putExtra("Info", info);
             startActivity(i);

    });
}
```

Comment: Where would I put this and how would I use it?

Comment: @user1928981, you can put this in onCreate method of your activity after declaring your button. I am editing my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link to another actvity, on click of a button, then you first need to set a listener that listens for the button's click. then you need to override the `onClick()` function to implement the functionality that you need on that particular button's click.

Here is a snippet of code, that could let you know how it works.

```
Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Send Button Clicked", 5000).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Data", data); //It is for any data you want to send to next activity
        startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```