# How do you execute a task at a click of a button?

Tags: android, button

I'm a beginner in Android programming.

How do you execute a task when a button is clicked? I have heard you can use the `onclick` method but I'm not quite sure how to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use OnClick in android programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036566/how-to-use-onclick-in-android-programming)

Comment: @Peter Quite definitely a duplicate.

Comment: Please do google first before posting any Questions. You have to learn Android Basics first. see http://developer.android.com/training/index.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

i think this will be useful:

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Put some code here for response to button click
        }
    });
```

Comment: You Welcome! Pls upvote, if you havent done yet :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in the *Activity*'s class as a function:

```
public void myFunction(View v){
   //all codes here for the click
}
```

Then in the design, select the *Button*, and in the property list look for the property "onclick". In the dropdown you will find your method listed there, choose it.
This will link you button click to the function being triggered.